# optimize.fsolve in case of multivariate functions

Tags: python, scipy

I need to solve an algebraic equation of the form `f(x,y)=0` and I know that the value of `y` is `y0`. One possible way to do this is by defining a new function that is only function of x

```
y0=0.1 
def g(x):
    return f(x,y=y0)
```

and then find the solution for the new function `g` using `fsolve` :

```
from scipy import optimize
solution = optimize.fsolve(g,x0=0.1)
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this? I would like to specify that I know the value of `y` without the need of defining a new function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `y0` or any other extra inputs  as `args` to the function.

Following is the minimal example.

```
def f(x,y):
  return 2*x*x - y
scipy.optimize.fsolve(func, x0=3, args=(5))  # y0=5


array([1.58113883])
```

Comment: Is it possible to indicate that the derivative must be made with respect to `y` rather than `x` in your example? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need derivative with respect to y ? Are you trying to solve for y ? or both x and y?

Comment: I misspoke. I meant how can I solve it for y in your example? Forget about derivatives.

Comment: The variable to be solved should the first parameter in the function definition. so function definition becomes def f(y,x) in this case .  The initial value of y should be passed as x0  and the value of  x should be passed as args while calling fsolve .